# PHP Fetching Data in the Background

Tags: php, cakephp, fetch, cakephp-2.1

We are building an Analytics App. Which will need the user to wait for 30 seconds while we fetch the data from another source and do some calculations before displaying it to the user.

Is there any way we can show a waiting page to the user while we fetch the data in the background rather than have the page load for 30 seconds as we fetch the data.

Can any one throw some light on how it can be done ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note : for lightbox, you have to include lightbox js

```
     <script>
    function onload_wating()
    {
    var syncronize_target=SITE_URL+'your_controllername/action_timer/';

    $.lightbox(syncronize_target, {
                width   : 450,
                height  : 260,
                'modal' : true,
                'onOpen'  : function() {    
                    $(".jquery-lightbox-button-close").css({"visibility":"hidden","display":"none"});
                }
            });
      }

    onload_wating();
    <script>
```

action_timer.ctp

Note : for countdown,you have to include jquery countdown -> http://keith-wood.name/countdown.html

```
     <script>
     $(function () {    
        $('#syncronize_header_timer').countdown(
                {
                until:+50,
                format: 'MS',
                onExpiry: ltliftOff
                }); 
    });

        function ltliftOff() {

            $.lightbox().close();
        }

    <script>
 <div id="syncronize_header_timer" ></div>
```

==========================================

Above onload_wating() this function open lightbox and make ajax query to ur controller action and open action_timer.ctp

in action_timer.ctp, we use countdown timer .
This timer count to 50, then its automatically close.

between this 50 second , you can retrive ur data from database.

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to poll a page on the server with HTTP GET requests using AJAX.

You can use the database or even better [APC](http://www.phpriot.com/articles/php-ajax-file-uploads/3)

EDIT:

Since we're not talking about a file upload here, the Session may be a better option than APC_UPLOAD_PROGRESS.    Sessions provide per user storage which should be ideal here, and can be backed by different stores like APC anyway.

Comment: yeah the data i am fetching i will be storing it in the database itself before displaying

Comment: The database just may not be the best place to put a backend for a polling mechanism if there is a lot of traffic.  APC is memory-resident on the Webserver so should be better for performance, but for smaller load I think the DB should be fine.

Comment: Actually now that I think of it, the Session might be better if it isn't an upload you're monitoring.  Same idea, the load is on the Webserver rather than the DB and will of course be highly portable.

Comment: i am fetching the data from Google Api.. i will be doing around 8 api calls to get various data then i need to store it in the database for the future too.